# Symfony Sonata Admin - add field type url in listView not working

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4, symfony-sonata

i'm trying to add a field type url in the list view of an entity, this is the link at the documentation -> https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/field_types.html#url .

This is my code, i've simply copied the documentation:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('name')
            ->add('url', 'url', [
                'url' => 'http://example.com'
            ]);
}
```

This seems to work but the column "Url" is always empty.

[image]

I found the template of Sonata that is responsible to render this field -> @SonataAdmin/CRUD/list_url.html.twig .
Here is the code

```
{% extends get_admin_template('base_list_field', admin.code) %}

{% block field %}
{% spaceless %}
   {% if value is empty %}
     &nbsp;
   {% else %}
      {% if field_description.options.url is defined %}
   ...
```

The problem is that **value** is always empty, i don't know what is this variable; and the documentation is not talking about any field named value.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work, I checked some github discussions. What you can do. Either create your own  custom field or map this url to object (save it in db).

Comment: Can you show us the url field in your entity, please. On the other hand you have written ->add('url', ...  instead of ->addIdentifier('url', ...

Comment: @M.Galardi The url field is not in my entity, i want to add an external url in the list. I have to use ->add and not ->addIdentifier like is explained in the docs "Do not use url type with addIdentifier() method, because it will create invalid nested URLs."

Comment: @revengeance do you have the links to the discussions? Maybe they could be useful also for reference of this problem on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you can achieve this by creating a template which simply contains a button with the URL you'd like to link to. See below:

First we define a field on the list view which references a template, the type is null:

```
->add('foo', null, [
    'template' => 'example/foobar.html.twig',
])
```

Inside our template we've just referenced, we can do the following:

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="http://google.co.uk/">My Link</a>
{% endblock %}
```

and now you should see the button display as a column on the list view.

It would be nice if the documented suggestion worked as intended, this solution is a work around.